# pandas: groupby and unstack to create feature vector for classification

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a pandas dataframe displaying users' performance on test questions. It looks like this:

```
userID     questionID   correct
-------------------------------
  1             1          1
  1             5          1
  1             6          0
  1             8          0
  1             10         1
  2             3          1
  2             5          1
  2             6          0
  .             .          .
  .             .          .
  .             .          .
```

I want to make a feature vector for each user saying whether or not they got each question right, that looks something like this:

```
questionID     1     2      3     4     5     6     ...
userID       -------------------------------------------------
  1            1    NaN   NaN    NaN    1     0     ...
  2           NaN   NaN    1     NaN    1     0     ...
  .           ...
  .           ...
  .
```

Each user only gets shown a subset of all the questions, so it's a sparse matrix.

How can I make the above table in pandas?

I wanted to do something like below - grouping by userID and questionID and then unstacking, but I'm not sure exactly how it should work.

```
df = df.groupby(['user_id','question_id'])
df.unstack()
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
In [11]: df.pivot(values='correct', index='userID', columns='questionID')
Out[11]: 
questionID  1   3   5   6   8   10
userID                            
1            1 NaN   1   0   0   1
2          NaN   1   1   0 NaN NaN
```

You might like to reindex the columns (based on all the questions) if you're not surjective.

```
In [12]: _.reindex_axis(np.arange(1, 10), 1)
Out[12]: 
         1   2   3   4  5  6   7   8   9
userID                                  
1        1 NaN NaN NaN  1  0 NaN   0 NaN
2      NaN NaN   1 NaN  1  0 NaN NaN NaN
```

Note: Originally this answer suggested [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) (which uses an aggfunc on repeated values, by default mean, and that's not what you want here - as @U2EF1 points out), it offers some other additional features over pivot but is a little slower:

```
df.pivot_table(values='correct', rows='userID', cols='questionID')
```

*I have this feeling that in older versions of pandas, pivot was sensitive to NaN so you had to use pivot_table...*

Comment: @user3591836 Note that this is going to average the `correct` column, so make sure that (userID, questionID) pairs are unique!

Comment: @U2EF1 great point, perhaps `pivot` is the correct function to use here (in my experience it's a little more sensitive though)... I was surprised it allows the NaN!

Comment: `df.pivot(index='userID', columns='questionID')` does exactly the same thing, both work fine. And pandas tries to be NaN friendly all over the place :)

Comment: @U2EF1 I have this feeling that pivot __used__ to not play well with missing data, but maybe I'm making that up. Thanks, updated the answer (definitely pivot is correct here)